# Unable to set Antlr4 Build Action in .Net Core 2 project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, antlr4, .net-core-2.0

I have created a .Net Core 2 project and wanted to add `Grammar.g4` file. I have added `Nuget` packages called "`ANtlr4`", "`Antlr4.Runtime`" and "`Antlr4.CodeGenerator`" with latest available version 4.6.4. Somehow, I am not able to change "`Build Action`" to `Antlr4` for my `Grammar.g4` file.
Because of that, it's not generating parser and lexer files.
Can anyone please help here what's wrong going on?

Comment: You need to unload/reload the project for the Antlr4 build action to be available after you install the NuGet package, try that.

Comment: I tried to unload and load but didn't help.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report for the [tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) project. The best way to get a solution for issues related to that project is to file an issue [on GitHub here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues). Otherwise, the maintainers of that project are likely to never see it.

Comment: Thanks Sam,
I have reported issue into the repository you suggested.